# How to use Excel to calculate concurrent streaks

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif, visual-basic

I want to use Excel to calculate the "best" and "current" streak in a range of data.

Say that a shop's sales target for the day is 500. I have a column which contains the daily sales data for the last 5 years. How can I use this data to calculate my best run of days meeting the sales target, and my current run of days.

I tried using COUNTIF(C:C,">=500") but the issue with this is that it just counts all the days the target was met, it does not count the best "streak", or record number of days in a row in which the target was met.

Sincerest thanks in advance.

Comment: In reallity you want to rank the streaks, which are made of consecutive days where you went above the target sales? If that's so I believe you will need VBA for this.

Comment: ... or a helper column. assuming it is `D` and your data starts in `C2`: use `IF(C2>=500, 1,"")` in `D2` and `IF(C3>=500, D2+1,"")` in `D3` and populate down. Then find the max value in that column

Comment: Not sure what is meant by the helper column approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helper column would make this easier. Let's see if we can do without it.

### Basic Approach

We're actually not going to use `COUNTIF` at all, just a simple incrementing counter.

[image: screenshot]

**Note** that we've made your sales target dynamic and defined it in cell `D1`. It turns out that it would be slightly simpler to have it elsewhere; so if you're following these instructions you might prefer to put it in `G1` instead and adjust all `$D$1` cell references that follow to `$G$1`.

### This formula works

`=IF(C2<$D$1,"dq",IF(AND(C1<$D$1,C2>=$D$1),1,D1+1))`

`=IF(C2<$D$1,"dq",`
If the current record doesn't qualify, disqualify it.

`IF(AND(C1<$D$1,C2>=$D$1),1,`
If the current record is the first consecutive qualifier (`C1<$D$1` tests the previous record for 'dq' status; `C2>=$D$1` tests the current record for qualification), make its value equal to 1

`D1+1))`
Else - that is, if the current record is neither a disqualified total or the first qualified total, make its value equal to one more than the record above it.

**This formula copies down from `D2`**. Note that it causes trouble in this exact setup if the first record (row 2) is a qualifying record AND you use `D1` as I have to define the target, since `D1` looks like a streak of 500. There are a number of trivial ways around this; for the purpose of the example I've just chosen to fiat that the first record doesn't qualify, for simplicity.

From here it should be pretty straightforward to add the next couple of features.

### Add 'longest streak'

[image: add MAX]

`=MAX(INDIRECT("D2:D"&COUNTA(D:D)))`

We're using a dynamic cell reference here so we don't have to worry about expanding the range. We can't use `D:D`, again, because that max would come back as the 500 in `D1`. But you could simply write `=MAX($D$2:$D$9999)` or whatever, if you want to. Using `INDIRECT` is good practice, anyway.

And then, presumably, you have identifying information in `A` and `B` - perhaps a date that you'd like to associate with your 'longest streak'?

### Associated data

[image: winning date]

`=INDEX(B:D,MATCH(G2,D:D,0),1)`

That's a straightforward `INDEX` `MATCH` to find the (*first*) instance of the longest streak achieved, as calculated in the cell above.

### Limitations

1. As I mentioned, because we're not using arrays or anything real complex, in the case of ties this returns the first occurrence of a streak of that length. I'd call this a feature - you haven't set a new record until you've *beaten* the last one, right?
2. For the same reason, this approach is not going to work very well if you want to know what and when were the *nth*-longest streaks for any values of *n* greater than 1. Well, it can tell you *what* those streaks were - use `LARGE` for that - but since the length of the (*nth*-longest streak where *n*>1) will, by definition, have occurred more than once, the lookup that pulls in the date for that streak is not going to work with this approach.
3. This requires the dataset to be as shown/given in your example - obviously, the sales records have to be arranged by date; perhaps more important to note that it's only set up to work for a sheet containing data for a single store.

Comment: If you put the threshold (`500`) in say, `G1` instead of `D1`, then you can use `D:D` in the formula and avoid `INDIRECT`

Comment: Yeah, by the time I was finished, it had clearly been a horrible decision to put it there in the first place, but all the screenshots were already done ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! Working very well, and very intuitive explanation.